# error: cannot find symbol method getSupportActionBar(),findViewById(int),getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I have this code inside my ScheduleFragment in which my objective was to view a simple calendar viewer. But unfortunately, it gets an error mentioned in the title. Even if I change "public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment" to "public class ScheduleFragment extends AppCompatActivity", it gives an error to @Override.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

CompactCalendarView compactCalendar;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM - yyyy", Locale.getDefault());


public ScheduleFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);

    final ActionBar actionBar =     getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setTitle(null);

    compactCalendar = (CompactCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.compactcalendar_view);
    compactCalendar.setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation(true);

    Event ev1 = new Event(Color.RED, 1477040400000L, "Teachers' Professional Day");
    compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);

    compactCalendar.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            if (dateClicked.toString().compareTo("Fri Oct 21 00:00:00 AST 2016") == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Teachers' Professional Day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Events Planned for that day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMonthScroll(Date firstDayOfNewMonth) {
            actionBar.setTitle(dateFormatMonth.format(firstDayOfNewMonth));
        }
    });

}                  

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fragments, you can not directly call `findViewById()` and have to use the view that you just inflated and call `findViewById()` on it.
So your onCreateView code will be,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);
    compactCalendar = (CompactCalendarView) v.findViewById(R.id.compactcalendar_view); 
   //Make sure that the view inflated above has these view elements which you are trying to initialize
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Similarly for `getApplicationContext()`, you first need to call `getContext()` and then call `getApplicationContext()` on it
So it becomes,

```
Context c = getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

Same goes for `getSupportActionBar();`

Comment: But is my execution right? I mean in the tutorial that I've seen, these codes are being done in MainActivity, which in my case I've put it in a fragment so it will respond lately in the NavigationDrawer. Am I in the right path?

Comment: I did what you said but when I click on the Schedule of my navigation drawer, it gives a not responding error. Is my code below for getSupportActionBar correct?:

final ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

Comment: What are the error/warning logs when you click the schedule.

Comment: There were no error/warning logs when I executed the app. the Logs were clean. So I dont know what else is the problem in here.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should inflate the view and use *view.findViewByID(R.id.id)*,
then  call return at the end of the method .

Comment: Already did. I'm having a different problem now. See my comment to Harshit Dwivedi above.