# App not responding error due to Fragment code

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So my code for schedule fragment are listed below. These codes are fixed from my [later error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453019/error-cannot-find-symbol-method-getsupportactionbar-findviewbyidint-getappl), but the problem is, it gives a Not responding error once I click `"My Schedule"` in my navigation drawer. Remember that my Schedule Fragment is connected to Navigation Drawer it self.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

CompactCalendarView compactCalendar;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM - yyyy", Locale.getDefault());


public ScheduleFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);

    final ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setTitle(null);

    compactCalendar = (CompactCalendarView) v.findViewById(R.id.compactcalendar_view);
    compactCalendar.setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation(true);

    Event ev1 = new Event(Color.RED, 1477040400000L, "Teachers' Professional Day");
    compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);

    compactCalendar.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {
            Context c = getContext().getApplicationContext();

            if (dateClicked.toString().compareTo("Fri Oct 21 00:00:00 AST 2016") == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Teachers' Professional Day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(c, "No Events Planned for that day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMonthScroll(Date firstDayOfNewMonth) {
            actionBar.setTitle(dateFormatMonth.format(firstDayOfNewMonth));
        }
    });
return v;
}
```

}

What seems to be the problem? Do I need to implement the `"extends ActionBarActivity"` or `"AppCompatActivity"`? Either of these to will result in error of `@Override method.`

Comment: Show error logs

Comment: Error logs are clean in my Android Studio

Comment: you need to extend AppCompatActivity